# Workaround for old MySQL version

Tags: magento2, database, installation

Is there any solution to install magento é with an older version of MySQL (5.5) and avoid the well know error:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

MySQL 5.6 is mandatory. So there should be no workaround for that.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, Magento 2 is not compatible with MySQL 5.5.

I could probably provide a workaround if I dig into the code but you'll most likely end up with bugs.

I strongly encourage you upgrade MySQL to at least 5.6.0